# Set year us a default value Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the field in model which will be default is the current. So i use the default parameter and editable is false, but i getting this error

> name 'Year' is not defined

My model

```
def Get_Year():
    year = datetime.date.today().year
    return year

class DisposalHeader(models.Model):
    DisposalSecondaryKey = models.UUIDField(unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    Year = models.IntegerField(editable=False, default=Get_Year)
    Sequence = models.IntegerField(editable=False, default=Sequence_SysGen)
    CostCenter = models.ForeignKey(CostCenter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Requestor = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    SiteLocation = models.ForeignKey(SiteLocation, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ItemType = models.ForeignKey(ItemType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Remarks = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
```

Error Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
 `year = datetime.datetime.now().year`

Comment: same error. Note: I getting error when i will manually add record using the admin page.

Comment: Check what type of data return that function. He must to be int not str

Comment: Can you share the whole traceback of the exception you get?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `Get_Year` function, as I don't really see a need for it.

And then change your model as follows:

```
year = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
```

And then in your template you can use the necessary formatting option if you only want to display the year.